# UML: Use a Java Interface (not the GUI) for MP3 Player

Tags: java, interface, mp3

I'm a noob tackling a simple mp3 player project. I'm planning out my project first and need to create a UML of my classes. So far I've got:

Player Class (play controls)
Playlist subClass (playlist control)
I'm open to any suggestions to class structure. This is my first project so I don't want to get in over my head. Now for my question. I'd like to incorporate an "interface" class file. What type of methods(s) would be ideal for this? As always, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! -Joseph

Answer (score 0):

You could use an interface to represent a media file capable of being read, like a song or a video clip; allowing your player to expand in the future. Something like:

```
public interface ReadableMedia {
    public byte[] readMedia();
    public String getName();
}
```

Just so you know, in cases like these, it is often a best practice of using an abstract class instead. Interfaces generally define **rules** whereas abstract classes define **concepts**. Let's take as an example the Song class; a song has a strong relationship with the media concept. When you notice this king of situation, you are better off creating an abstract class.

I hope this helped a little.